# How to make a phone call in background using cordova?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

for a project I would like to make a phone call, from a cordova app without showing the calling view. So it should call a number in background. Is this possible, maybe using the hidden InApp Browser feature?

Any help is appreciated. The App is running on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cordova-plugin-phone-call](https://github.com/lakshmansha/cordova-plugin-phone-call) but this is for android only. There is also the [CordovaCall](https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/CordovaCall) plugin that works on Android and iOS

Comment: Thank you - but is this running in background, or showing up the regular Phone Call UI?

Comment: No, the call interface is brought up and depending on options, the call is placed directly without user interactions. Then you could use cordova-plugin-bring-to-front to bring back the cordova to front (untested)